# Error when adding custom web part to a page

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I have a web part I have developed in Visual Studio. It just goes out to a document library and gets all the items:

```
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.GetItems();
```

This works fine. But whenever I try to include a query:

```
SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
qry.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Name\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Modified\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Url\"/>";
qry.ViewFieldsOnly = true; // Fetch only the data that we need.
qry.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";

SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.GetItems(qry);
```

and try to add the web part to a page I get the following error on the page:

> Failed to render "Wiki Content" column because of an error in the
>   "multiple lines of text" field type control. Value does not fall
>   within the expected range

Comment: Do you have any other web part in this page and where is your qry.Query? You should set the Query property also.

Comment: No other web part. I tried setting the query property too but the same result. The difference between getting the error and not getting it has to do with using a query: GetItems(qry) vs GetItems()

Comment: does oDocumentLibrary.GetItems(qry); return any items?

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to my ViewFields SPQuery property settings. I must have been using the wrong field names. "Name" is supposed to be "LinkFilename" and "Url" is supposed to be "ServerUrl". I was basing the field names off the SPListItem object model names which are "Name" and "Url". Thanks to Atish for making me check my query results.

Comment: That's all right! In CAML query, don't forget to user internal name of fields